# In PHP5, how do I create an associative array from a database query?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, associative-array

I am creating a class for an application "backbone" and I need this function to query the db, and return a multidimensional to look like this:

```
$myArray = ("name"=>"John", "dob"=>"January 5, 1955");
```

Of course the data for the array is from a database query.
but, "name" and "dob" would be the database column name and "John" and "January 5, 1955" would be the value of the column

Here is my code:

```
public function getFrame($id) {
    $getFrameQuery = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_FRAMETABLE . "WHERE `fhid`=" . $this->quote_smart($id);
    $getFrameRecord = $db->query_first($getFrameQuery);          
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What database wrapper are you using? They usually provide a way to retrieve a row into an associative array.

mysql_fetch_assoc(), for example

From your comment to the other answer, the wrapper you are using provides a ->fetch_array() method that returns the data structure you are looking for.

Looks like you would need to change your code to use something like

```
$result = $db->query($getFrameQuery);
$data = $db->fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: thanks. What type of array did I use as an example for future reference?

Comment: @josh brown: An associative array. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: you used an associative or hash array, 

key => value  

A multidimensional array could have been (key => "value1", "value2")

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a multidimensional array. Just a regular associative array.

Comment: So the DB query returns a associative array?

Comment: I am using this mysql class wrapper: http://www.ricocheting.com/scripts/php_mysql_wrapper.php

Comment: Seems as if query_first() does return an associative array, the column names as keys. $getFrameRecord['name'] would get you "John"

Comment: $query = "select name from whatever";

$results = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
   echo $row['name'];
}